# ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:3306' (111)

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, ubuntu, root

use the following command:

```
mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 -p
```

and the error message is :

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)
```

Who can help me to fix it?

Comment: Is this even related to programming? If yes, please share more details

Comment: How did you start mySql?  Did you run:  `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start` or similar?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Check mysql.conf and sure that you have this: **bind-address = 127.0.0.1** and comment it #

Then restart mysql service

Answer (score 0):

If you use Macports, edit /opt/local/etc/mysql57/macports-default.cnf and comment **skip-networking** line.

After that, restart mysql server.